# Where to find the website's homepage in expressionengine?

Tags: ee2, control-panel, structure

I m trying to change the tag title  of the homepage but I can't locate the homepage in the cms . I can't edit the layout page since it generates the tag title dynamically on the code below . Does anyone know how to locate the home page in the cms  ?

```
{!--choozle tag--}
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//nexus.ensighten.com/choozle/200/Bootstrap.js"></script>
{!--end choozle--}

{if layout:meta_title}
     <title>{layout:meta_title} | {site_name} </title>
     <meta name='description' content='{layout:meta_description}' />
     <meta property="og:description" content=" {layout:meta_description}" />
     <meta property="og:title" content=">{layout:meta_title}" />

{if:else}
   {exp:seo_lite use_last_segment="yes"}
{/if}


{if layout:og-image}
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="{layout:og-image}" >
{if:else}
    <meta property="og:image:url" content="{lv-og-url}/images/og-logo.png" >
{/if}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the website's homepage isn't an entry, but a only a template: the `index.html` template of the [default template group](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/design/group/form.html#make-default-group).

For version 3, on control panel, go to [Developer Tools -> Template Manager](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/design/index.html) and search for the template with a house icon.

For version 2, on control panel, go to [Design -> Templates -> Template Manager](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/design/templates/templates.html). Search for the template group with an asterisk and the template wit a house icon.

On your case, look there for the `layout:meta_title` variable.

If you need to edit the group, but can't do it on CP, look at the `index.php` or `config.php` and search for [config overrides](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html). There are two related to this matter: [`template_group`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#overrides-template-group) and [`template`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#overrides-template).

Comment: I can't find the developer tools menu on the ExpressionEngine v2.10.1. Where is it ? do you think the developer didn't open that option ?

Comment: @NgomaMbakuDavy, you should have informed the version you're using. I updated the answer. If you can edit the layout template, you can edit the others.

Comment: thank you for the answer but this V2 is very complicated to use . You said go to design , well i dont even see the design option on the menu .Those below are the main item on  my menu . Publish ,Edit ,File Manager ,Site,Config,Nav,Reorder,Change Password . Under which item is going to be the design ?

Comment: @NgomaMbakuDavy , the items of menu can be set on a user group basis. It looks like you don't have permission to see all items. How You found the layout template? At a directory on server? You should hire a developer.

Comment: I found the layout page by logging it Via FTP. I m a adeveloper but  i m very new to this engine .

Comment: You can search for some home page element on all `index.html` files. But there's probably a good reason for who set the system up to have hide the Design CP section. A eecms professional can guess the template just looking at the template directory structure. Update your question with it and I can try to help you.